# How to change a Glossary within the text, referencing to its original?

Tags: glossaries

Is there a way to make a crossreference with a Glossary for example in Plural within the text to its Glossary Entry that is set in singular? I just would like to know how i can make there a "Transformation" of the original. Something like `\gls[new]{original}` doesn´t work.

Edit: `\glspl` just adds an "s" and this doesn´t solve my problem.

Comment: You can explicitly define a plural form. e.g. `plural = {babies}` then use `\glspl` ? If not, can you be more explicit about what you want? Give an example, best if it is a compilable code snippet.

Comment: ok, i solved it with \glslink xD Anyway: thanks for help! :)

Comment: @NilsKohlmey You need to put your solution in the answer area below otherwise this question will remain on the unanswered list and will keep resurfacing. (You can self-answer and mark it as accepted.)

Comment: ok, sorry. Done!

Answer (score 1):

Solved with: `\glslink{label}{alternate text}`